# Modules that will allow search for external data using either Apache Solr or Elastic Search

Tags: search

I have data within a Teamsite application which we will be indexing within either Apache Solr or Elastic Search (have not decided yet).  I plan on creating search pages within Drupal 7 that will allow the user to search against the external indexed data mentioned above and list the search within a Drupal results page.

Are there any Drupal 7 module that will allow this to done for external data using either Apache Solr or Elastic Search similar to what can be done with Drupal 7 modules that connect to Solr or Elastic Search for Drupal indexed data?

Answer (score 1):

You need **Search API** with either of the plugin modules. Search API is a fantastic way to abstract out the engine from the logic. Although I've only use the Solr implementation I've spoken with several developers who have switched to Elastic.

- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api
- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr
- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_elasticsearch

Search API also works with Facet API (which supports the ApacheSolr module too -- the 'competitor' to Search API).
https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi

In Drupal 8 those two modules (Search API and ApacheSolr) have become one.

Comment: I thought that the search_api_solr and search_api_elasticsearch modules only work if the indexed content is from Drupal and not from an external datastore like Teamsite.

Comment: Beg your pardon I misread your question. However take a look at the examples here and I'll update my answer. https://www.drupal.org/node/1999668

Answer (score 0):

I found the Sarnia drupal module appears to handle external data indexed within Apache Solr so that it can be searched within Drupal but I found no such module for Elastic Search.